# How to create a new objects of array by using object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two objects.

```
let obj1={"1":"Func P1","2":"Geo P2","3":"Calc P1","4":"Calc P2"}

let obj2={"1":"11","2":"44","3":"66","4":"88"}
```

I'd like to use values to create the following:

```
[{ myX: "Func P1", myY: 11 }, { myX: "Geo P2", myY: 44 },{ myX: "Calc P1", myY: 66},{myX: "Calc P2", myY: 88 }]
```

Is it possible to do it?

I tried this so far:

```
let combined = [];
      for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(obj1)) {
        for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(ojb2)) {
          combined.push({ myX: value1, myY: value2 });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

I've used `+` to convert it to `Number` type, you can also use `parseInt` or `Number` also

```
+obj2[key]
```

```js
let obj1 = { "1": "Func P1", "2": "Geo P2", "3": "Calc P1", "4": "Calc P2" };

let obj2 = { "1": "11", "2": "44", "3": "66", "4": "88" };

const result = Object.keys(obj1).map((key, index) => ({
  myX: obj1[key],
  myY: +obj2[key],
}));
console.log(result);
```